# What do I do with my juvenile leopard gecko while going on vacation?

Tags: reptiles, leopard-geckos

I have a juvenile leopard gecko, I will be going on vacation soon for 3 days. I don't know if he'll be okay while I'm gone? I will feed him before I go, but I usually feed him 10-15 crickets every other day. But, I wont be there for 3 day and I'm scared he'll be starving while I'm gone.

Answer (score 3):

### Good to go!

Doing a feeding before you go is plenty, your gecko will survive the 3 day vacation without any worries.

Their tails are made as an energy reserve, they can go many weeks without a meal by utilizing the fat [stored in their tails](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25935709).

### A Few Tidbits

- Ensure he has plenty of water
- Ensure temps stay at an adequate level to prevent him from getting too cold or too hot.

  - [How do I keep my leopard gecko cage warm?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17045/how-do-i-keep-my-leopard-gecko-cage-warm)
- If possible have his lighting set to a timer so it can automatically turn on/off at the appropriate times.